# Is there a way to cache my own GCR image to avoid pulling it every build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml, google-cloud-registry

I have a build where this image is stored in my GCR and I want to reduce the time as it takes several minutes to pull each time. Is there a way to cache this image so each time it can be instantly taken from a cache?

```
# Run tests
- name: 'gcr.io/{Project name}/{name of my image}'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
  - -c 
  - |
    make run-tests
  id: run-tests
```

So I want to somehow cache this `'gcr.io/{Project name}/{name of my image}'` As every build, it takes several minutes for Pulling fs layer, Waiting, Verifying Checksum, Download complete. So my later build steps this is cached as it says `Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/{Project name}/{name of my image}`. I basically want to get that line at the top of my tests too

Comment: Just curious what's the size of your custom image?

Comment: @CaioT The custom image is just above 5GB

Comment: I am facing the same issue and am curious about this as well.